# Backing up the database and recovering to the back up if the primary system is down

Tags: sql, oracle, backup, oracle-apex

I am currently using oracle apex an online version of oracle RDBMS and I don't have a clue how to back up my database/system. After some research , I found out that most people use RMAN to do this type of process which of backing up the system and automatically uses the backup if the system is down.

I also stumbled upon TSPITR, it would also be helpful if someone points out the differences between these two.

Is it possible to perform a back up and automatically use the backup system when the primary system is down on Oracle Apex ?

Comment: Are you the DBA in addition to being the APEX developer?  Backup and recovery of a database is very much in the DBA realm and knowing exactly how your environment has been configured will impact the answer.  For example, are all your APEX application's objects in a single tablespace?  Are there other objects in that tablespace?  Do you even have privileges to run a RMAN backup?  As an APEX developer, you can certainly back up your APEX application via the APEX builder and then restore that application in a different database (that's what the packaged apps are).

Comment: Yes I Created the schema and database myself but when I tried to go to the Utilities -> Database Monitor -> Long Operations , it asked me to login as someone with admin privileges, so inserted my credentials but it states that 'User does not have required role' , is there a way to assign my account to an admin role ?

Comment: What do you mean that you created the database and the schema?  If you created the database yourself then you would have had to install APEX, configure Enterprise Manager, etc. and one of the default steps would have been to set up an automatic backup.  It's possible that you did that but I would guess that you don't mean that you created what Oracle calls a database.  If you are the DBA and you installed APEX, when you created your APEX account you probably made it a developer rather than a workspace administrator.  I would expect that is what prevents you from hitting that screen.

Comment: I'm using the online version Oracle Application Express , does that make any difference sorry for being a bit of a slow timer but I'm rather new to this platform...

Comment: I think I might have found a solution in the Packaged Apps as there is an application called Apex Application Archive which might do the trick, by any chance have you ever used this ?

Comment: You mean apex.oracle.com?  In that case, you didn't create the database or the schema.  You requested a workspace but Oracle created that for you.  You can't back up the database.  You can export your application through the APEX builder interface.  You shouldn't be running any sort of "live" application on apex.oracle.com.  I've never looked at that particular packaged app.

Comment: Yes ! Right now I'm using this to experiment with some PL SQL , but thanks for the tip :)